# nothing happened if input code . in visual studio code terminal to open azure cloud shell

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-cloud-shell

With Azure account extension and node.js installed on Visual Studio code, I cannot open cloud shell with `code .` after sign in successfully.

Am I missing any steps? refer this doc:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cloudshelleditor/

[image]

Also, I would like to use `vi` command to edit the file.

If I would like to edit the contents in 1.txt, I can only move up and down with `ctrl+up` and `ctrl+down`, but not able to move left and right. How we can move left and right with the `vi` command. If it is a limitation of the command, any other ways/ approaches to edit the files?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an expected behavior as the [linked](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/cloudshelleditor/) statements the visual Studio code is integrated into Azure cloud shell.

> Through collaboration with the Visual Studio Code team and their
>   open-source Monaco project, the same web-standards based editor that
>   powers Visual Studio Code is now integrated directly into Cloud Shell.

Azure Cloud Shell includes an integrated file editor built from the open-source Monaco Editor. By running `code .` in the Cloud Shell terminal. This action opens the editor with your **active working directory set** in the terminal. See [Using the Azure Cloud Shell editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/using-cloud-shell-editor).

In fact, inputting `code .` is used to make you open the VS code editor. Now you have [used Cloud Shell in Visual Studio Code](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-use-cloud-shell-in-visual-studio-code/ba-p/663431), nothing will happen when you input `code.` in the Visual Studio code terminal. You also can compare the file directories in the Azure cloud shell with the file directories when you open **BASH in the cloud shell** in the Visual Studio Code.

[image]