# Connecting VScode to Azure Cloudshell

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, azure-cloud-shell

**Answer:**
TLDR: type `code .` in azure Cloudshell in browser to get file editor. (Using own IDE is not possible, only cloudshell as terminal)

---

I'm looking to connect VS Code to Azure Cloudshell, especially for the file explorer component.

It is a bit of an anti-pattern, but cloudshell is the only way in which I am able to run some commands that connect to Azure resources (spinning up a VM is not allowed).

I know the '[remote-ssh](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh)' extension can connect to a remote machine and provide a nice file explorer, however, for cloudshell I do not have ssh available. However, there is a connection possible through the '[Azure account](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account)' extension.
(There is also a '[remote tunnel](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.remote-server)' extension that is able to establish connections over different protocol than ssh).

This is the connection that 'Azure account' sets up with the cloudshell:

```
Netid  State   Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port          Process  
tcp    ESTAB   0        0          10.xxx.xx.169:http-alt      10.xxx.xx.29:57404            
tcp    ESTAB   0        0          10.xxx.xx.169:51710        20.xxx.xx.200:microsoft-ds
```

Does anybody know if this can be used to get a full remote development experience in VScode connected to Azure cloudshell?

(I tried to install the [vs code server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) rpm package in cloudshell, failed due to lacking yum and sudo permissions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below steps to connect to `Azure Cloud shell` (PowerShell/Bash).

- Open `VSCode`, = >`Extensions` => search for `Azure Account`.
  Check whether `Azure Account` is Installed and Enabled.

[image]

- If it is not done, Install and Enable it.

[image]

- We need to Login to Azure Account to Open the Cloud shell.
- In `View` tab => `Command Palette` => `Azure: Sign in`

[image]

***OR***

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` => `Azure: Sign in`.

- Click on Sign in and login to Azure.
  [image]

[image]

- You
- In the right, click on the `dropdown` symbol beside `+` .You will find an option for `Azure Cloud shell` (PowerShell / Bash).
- Select `Azure Cloud shell (PowerShell)` .
  [image]
- If it is not sign into Azure, you will get an option to Sign in.

[image]

- Once after Sign, you will get the below message in the terminal.
  [image]
- To make sure we are connected to Azure Cloud shell, execute any of the PowerShell command and check once.

[image]

> file explorer component

Thanks @[Brendan Burn](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/cloudshelleditor/) for the Post.

Refer this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61264829/nothing-happened-if-input-code-in-visual-studio-code-terminal-to-open-azure-cl) regarding File Explorer.

Comment: Hi Harshitha, thanks for the info, this is very useful, just to double check: this methods allows to only open a file editor inside cloudshell, and not use our standard IDE, correct?

Comment: @Roelof's - Yes, you are correct.